# On an asymptotic hyperbola with horizontal asymptote y = 100, how can I identify the first coordinate pair in which y = 99 or greater?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I recently played a number of games of Windows Freecell. Not being an expert, I failed to solve 9 games out of a slightly larger set of games. I then won all subsequent games, leaving me with a games won/games played record of about 70% to date.

Assuming I win all games after this, how many consecutive games won would be needed to produce a 99% won/played ratio?

I got this far:

let f(x) = total number of games won
let x = total number of games played

So at any point in the competition from now on, f(x) = x-9

such that

```
x    f(x)   (y/x)*100
9    0      0
10   1      10
11   2      18
12   3      25
...
```

I could sense from the behaviour of the 'Percentage won' values displayed in Freecell after each win that the proportion of (games won) : (total games played) will approach 1:1 (or y = 100) asymptotically. By filling in data tables in a spreadsheet, I confirmed that generating a sequence of ouput values for (y/x)*100 produces an asymptotic hyperbola. See [Plot of values for (y/x)*100 where f(x) = x-9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2X1XR.jpg)

I believe my problem can be stated as follows:

On the graph of an unknown (by me) hyperbolic function constructed with the methods given above, and with a horizontal asymptote y = 100, find the first coordinate pair in which y = or > 99.

f(x) = (x-9) gives the linear graph of the relationship between games won and games played, but how do you actually calculate the first coordinate pair of which y = or > 99?

Answer (score 0):

We have to solve $$\frac{x-9}{x}\ge 0.99$$

First we multiply with $x$ (for $x>0$ the greater-equal sign does not change)

We get $$x-9\ge 0.99x$$

Subtarct $0.99x$ and add $9$ to get

$$0.01x\ge 9$$

Finally, multiply with $100$

$$x\ge 900$$

So, you need $900$ games. You have then won $891$, which is $99$% of $900$.